# Go lang and Revel web framework don't work

Tags: web, go, frameworks, revel

I'm trying to use Revel web framework in WINDOWS 7 and am having trouble.
Simply follow the steps in the [Quick Start] page [http://revel.github.io/]:

c:\dev> go get github.com/revel/cmd/revel

c:\dev> revel run github.com/revel/revel/samples/chat

My GOROOT and GOPATH configuration are:

GOPATH =/Users/nery/DEV/go

GOROOT =/soft/go

I have also tried

GOPATH = c:\Users\nery\DEV\go

GOROOT = c:\soft\go

However in no response comes in Browser (Chrome) and the server is generated the following error output:

```
2015/01/14 10:07:56 harness.go:165: Listening on :9000                          
2015/01/14 10:07:58 reflect.go:775: Unexpected! Code path is not in GOPATH: \sof
t\go\src/github.com\revel\revel\samples\chat/app                                
2015/01/14 10:07:58 reflect.go:94: Skipping code path \soft\go\src/github.com\re
vel\revel\samples\chat/app                                                      
2015/01/14 10:07:58 reflect.go:775: Unexpected! Code path is not in GOPATH: \sof
t\go\src\github.com\revel\revel\modules\static/app                              
2015/01/14 10:07:58 reflect.go:94: Skipping code path \soft\go\src\github.com\re
vel\revel\modules\static/app                                                    
2015/01/14 10:07:58 reflect.go:775: Unexpected! Code path is not in GOPATH: \sof
t\go\src\github.com\revel\revel\modules\testrunner/app                          
2015/01/14 10:07:58 reflect.go:94: Skipping code path \soft\go\src\github.com\re
vel\revel\modules\testrunner/app                                                
2015/01/14 10:07:58 reflect.go:775: Unexpected! Code path is not in GOPATH: \sof
t\go\src/github.com\revel\revel\samples\chat/tests                              
2015/01/14 10:07:58 reflect.go:94: Skipping code path \soft\go\src/github.com\re
vel\revel\samples\chat/tests                                                    
2015/01/14 10:07:58 server.go:1775: http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:50903: runtime
 error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference                       
goroutine 26 [running]:                                                         
net/http.func·011()                                                             
        c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1130 +0xc2                                 
github.com/revel/revel/harness.(*SourceInfo).ControllerSpecs(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
```

.
.
.

Does anyone have any tips that can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Show output of `go env`. Do **not** set GOROOT.

Comment: Having had it but did not work. I tried again and still returning the same error. You must set GOROOT as the go is not installed in the default directory (c:\go). Reinstalled golang the default directory and still did not work, continues to generate the same error.

Comment: Install Go to its default, do not set GOROOT and post the output of `go env`. Something is wrong with your GOPATH.

Comment: Thank Volker. It worked! If I install golang in a directory other than the default and set the variable GOROOT does not work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Volker, you can answer the question with the tip you gave me, please.
So I can vote for your response, a response that helped me. Thank U!